# How do I make emacs display a multi-byte encoded file, properly? Is it mule?

Tags: emacs, unicode, multibyte

When I open a multi-byte file, I get this:

[image]

Comment: check what describe-current-encoding-system has to say.
You want it to say utf-16le, and it probably says utf-8. Can you confirm ?

Comment: last question: what version of emacs are you using ? versions prior to 23 are not great with unicode.

Comment: I use v22.2.1 of emacs on windows.

Comment: ok, I don't know what's going on... I had used a powershell script to modify an XML file.  When I opened the file you saw the result.  Now I've done it again, and when I open the file I get utf-16le, and it displays properly.  Not sure why.  Thank you for the hint on describe-current-coding-system .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If memory serves, Emacs will prompt the User for an encoding if it cannot determine one.  When it makes a wrong determination you can use

```
C-x RET f coding RET
```

which will use `coding` as the coding system for the visited file in the current buffer.

Answer (score 11):

Short term, you can revisit the file with an alternate coding system with `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` (select utf-16le then).

Middle term, you can bump the priority of that utf-16le encoding on load with `prefer-coding-system`.

Long term, however, you'd better try to understand why emacs did not pick the right encoding. I'm not sure how I can help there though, short of digging inside the coding system guts, or at least have a file to reproduce.

EDIT: Does this file have a [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) ?

Answer (score 0):

In xml files, Emacs takes this is big endian, while Windows takes this as little endian.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<hi />
```

Trying something like encoding="UTF-16LE" or encoding="UTF16-16BE" will ruin the xml file after saving.  It will take off the BOM.  utf-16le no bom can be opened in Notepad.