# How to display non-English characters on the Linux console?

Tags: linux, unicode, console

im using ubuntu without any x windows installed.
is it possible to show non english character in emacs shell mode ?
when i open the unicode file in emac character displaying in broken mode.

Comment: I take it you're using emacs in a terminal? In this case, you need to make sure you're using a terminal that supports unicode. Can you display unicode outside of emacs? If so, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708053/2043465) should solve your problem.

Comment: @Yossarian , yes im in terminal mode plus i checked it , i cant show the unicode in other editors to like vi , nano or pico .

Comment: This maybe a limitation of your terminal then. What happens when you use `less`? Do you see the characters you expect? If not, [you may wish to read this](http://superuser.com/questions/556993/how-to-display-unicode-in-a-linux-virtual-terminal).

Comment: @Yossarian , in less the character still messed up. i checked the link its changing the kernel and im low level user without privilage. so i guess its impossible for application like emac to emulate unicode in terminal mode without support of the terminal it self ?

Comment: I don't think so, no. There may be a way to change your virtual terminal to one that supports unicode though. That would be a better question for superuser.com